why doesn't my binary search method return -1 when it the target number doesn't appear in the array? It goes into a loop
public static int binarySearch(int[] x, int target) {
        int left = 0; 
        int right = x.length - 1; 
        int mid = (right + left ) / 2; 

        
        while ( left <= right) {
            mid = (right + left) / 2; 
            
            if (x[mid] == target) {
                return mid;
            }
            
            else if (x[mid] > target) {
                right = mid--  ; 
            }
            
            else if (x[mid] < target ) {
                left = mid ++;  
            }
        }
        return -1; 
    }
    

say the code is:
    public static void main(String args[] ) { 
        int[] myArr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};   

        System.out.println(binarySearch(myArr, 11));
    }

it never prints out -1, instead it goes in a loop where:
mid: 10
left: 9
right: 10
how can I fix this?

Have you run the code using a debugger ? When you run the code step-by-step, when does it first behave contrary to what you expected? What are the values of variables at that point?   "Using a debugger is an expected basic skill"

you shouldn't do mid-- and mid++, you should do right=mid-1 and left=mid+1 in the conditions

Using the while loop is, in my opinion confusing. You are trying to search the array for a value, which I think I think a for loops is more suited for. In the while loop you have nothing to increment the value of left so the condition stays in the true state.
Here is a suggested fix:
public static int binarySearch(int[] x, int target) {
        int left = 0; 
        int right = x.length - 1; 
        int mid = (right + left ) / 2; 

        for (left = 0; left < x.length - 1;  left ++) {
            mid = (right + left) / 2; 
        
            if (x[mid] == target) {
                return mid;
            }
        
            else if (x[mid] > target) {
                right = mid--  ; 
            }
        
            else if (x[mid] < target ) {
                left = mid ++;  
            }
        }
        return -1;      
        }

     public static void main(String args[] ) {
         int[] myArr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
         System.out.println(binarySearch(myArr, 11));
     }

This code uses a for loop to iterate through the array (x.length - 1) and return the value for the binary search method you wrote.

When I see a for loop, I expect a linear iteration - which is exactly what binary search is not. I'd say you made the code more confusing. And I don't even know if this fixes the issue (and if so - how).
